# my software model has some kind of cyclic dependency

Tags: java, design-patterns, modeling

I need a recommendation about my software model.

I think it is not that good, since there is some kind of cyclic dependency.

I have an OSGI bundle under [Kura application framework](https://www.eclipse.org/proposals/technology.kura/), here are the classes:

- Main class: the entry point of the bundle
- TwoWaySerialComm: for serial communication with an Arduino device
- SerialReader: responsible for reading from the serial port the data coming from the Arduino and then it sends the received data to the cloud using KURA service DataService.

  ```
  class Main {
      public static DataService m_dataService;//KURA service to send information to the cloud via MQTT  

      protected void activate(ComponentContext componentContext) {
      serialCom = new TwoWaySerialComm();//responsible for serial communication
        serialCom.connect("/dev/ttyUSB0"); 
      }
  }

  class TwoWaySerialComm {
      void connect(String portName) {
          //code omitted
          in = serialPort.getInputStream();
          //add event listener to read data from the serial port
          serialPort.addEventListener(new SerialReader(in));
          //code omitted
      }
  }

  public class SerialReader  implements SerialPortEventListener  {
      public void serialEvent(SerialPortEvent arg0) {

          //code for serial port reading omitted

          //the data obtained from the serial is sent to the
          //cloud via MQTT using the KURA service DataService as the following:
          Main.m_dataService.publish();
      }
  }
  ```

It is a bad modelling, if so how can I fix it?

Comment: Your question is extremely unclear. What is `A`? What does it do? What are its responsibilities? What is `ClassC`? What does it do? What are its responsibilities? What is `B`? What does it do? What are its responsibilities? What is `attributeA`? How is it used? Where is it used? What is `methodA`? What does it do? What are its responsibilities? What is `methodB`? What does it do? What are its responsibilities? What is `methodC`? What does it do? What are its responsibilities? How does your question differ from the other "what to do about cyclic dependencies" questions that have been answered?

Comment: I am sorry for the non precision, I edited my question with more details. Thanks

Comment: @sabrina2020 the code is still syntactically incorrect and it is unclear how **SerialReader** interacts with the other classes.  I've provided an answer based on incomplete information which may be enough for you to resolve the design gap here.

Comment: @sabrina2020 I figured it out. TwoWaySerialComm needs a SerialPortEventListener so the dependency inversion solution is also the correct solution there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the excessive knowledge of other classes and the corresponding tight coupling is bad.

Good news! It's easily resolved with *dependency inversion*.

The key flaw is that **SerialReader** knows that **Main** has its **DataService** dependency.  It doesn't need to know this, and shouldn't.  Instead it should be constructed with a **DataService**.  This is called *dependency inversion* or *dependency injection*.

SerialReader.java:

```
public final class SerialReader  implements SerialPortEventListener {
    private final DataService dataService;

    public SerialReader(DataService dataService) {
        this.dataService = dataService;
    }

    public void serialEvent(SerialPortEvent arg0) {
        //code for serial port reading omitted

        //the data obtained from the serial is sent to the 
        //cloud via MQTT using the KURA service DataService as the following: 
        dataService.publish(); 
    }
}
```

The same technique can be applied with even more flourish on **TwoWaySerialComm** as it can depend on the **SerialPortEventListener** interface instead of a specific class making it very loosely coupled.

TwoWaySerialComm.java

```
final class TwoWaySerialComm  {
    private final SerialPortEventListener serialPort;

    TwoWaySerialComm(SerialPortEventListener serialPort) {
        this.serialPort = serialPort;
    }

    void connect(String portName)  {
        //code omitted
        in = serialPort.getInputStream();
        //add event listener to read data from the serial port
        serialPort.addEventListener(new SerialReader(in));
        //code omitted
    }
}
```

And the **Main** does its job which is, and should always be, restricted to wiring up dependencies and starting the system.

Main.java:

```
final class Main  {
    //KURA service to send information to the cloud via MQTT
    public static final DataService dataService;

    protected void activate(ComponentContext componentContext) {
        SerialReader serialReader = new SerialReader(dataService);
        TwoWaySerialComm serialCom = new TwoWaySerialComm(serialReader);//responsible for serial communication
        serialCom.connect("/dev/ttyUSB0");
    }
}
```

You may notice I've renamed **m_dataService** to **dataService**.  The **m_** is occasionally used in C++, but is considered bad style in Java.

Answer (score 2):

This seems like a problematic design. If a class can't stand on its own, it effectively becomes part of an unintended meta-Frankenstein class along with its hard dependencies. In this case, `Main`, `TwoWaySerialComm`, and `SerialReader` are effectively one class, maybe `MainTwoWaySerialCommSerialReader`.

I can see a couple ways around it.

If `Main` requires a reference to the `DataService`, share that reference as a parameter to `TwoWaySerialComm` and ultimately `SerialReader`. Don't expose it as a public member.

```
class Main {

    private static DataService m_dataService;

    protected void activate(ComponentContext componentContext) {    
      serialCom = new TwoWaySerialComm();
      serialCom.connect("/dev/ttyUSB0", m_dataService); 
    }
}

class TwoWaySerialComm{
    void connect (String portName, DataService service) {
       in = serialPort.getInputStream();
       serialPort.addEventListener(new SerialReader(in, service));
    }
}

public class SerialReader implements SerialPortEventListener {

    private Stream in;
    private DataService service;

    SerialReader (Stream in, DataService service) {
        this.in = in;
        this.service = service;
    }

    public void serialEvent(SerialPortEvent arg0) {
        this.service.publish();
    }
}
```

Now, both `TwoWaySerialComm` and `SerialReader` can be used in other contexts. They don't require `Main`.

Another option is to push responsibility for the `DataService` closer to where it's used. If it's feasible, the `SerialReader` could "own" it.

```
class Main {    
    protected void activate(ComponentContext componentContext) {    
      serialCom = new TwoWaySerialComm();
      serialCom.connect("/dev/ttyUSB0"); 
    }
}

class TwoWaySerialComm{
    void connect (String portName) {
       in = serialPort.getInputStream();
       serialPort.addEventListener(new SerialReader(in));
    }
}

public class SerialReader implements SerialPortEventListener {

    private Stream in;
    private DataService service;

    SerialReader (Stream in) {
        this.in = in;
        // Not sure if this is possible.
        // If it is, it reduces the need to juggle the DataService
        // reference between classes.         
        this.service = ResolveDataServiceSomehow();
    }

    public void serialEvent(SerialPortEvent arg0) {
        this.service.publish();
    }
}
```

Comment: I like this. It cuts to the core of the design gap. What do you think of the dependency inversion approach I suggested?

Comment: @AlainO'Dea I like your solution - much improvement with little cost. Nice.

Comment: the book Clean Code has a lot of gems like this in it. Totally levelled up my game after reading it. Single best book on software craftsmanship that I've read. http://www.barnesandnoble.com/mobile/w/clean-code-robert-c-martin/1101628669?ean=9780132350884